# Making non-self delegate in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

In order to use asynchronous http requests in objective c, you need to set a delegate to `NSURLConnection`. The problem is that I need to make multiple http requests, so having the same delegate (self) wont work.

What is the best way to go about this? Should I make a new delegate class for each http request? Are these delegates just NSObjects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options.  The two most most common are:

- Make a new class for each connection (yes, a subclass of `NSObject`) and set them as delegates -- have them carry out whatever logic you need when the data is loaded
- Set one class as the delegate and store references to all of your `NSURLConnection`s. That way, when your delegate gets `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` called, you can test which `NSURLConnection` is being used (eg `if ([connection == myConnection])` -- or whichever delegate method you're implementing)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is make a class that will handle downloading a file, and notify me when it is done through a selector. I pass it a delegate, a selector and the Info it needs to perform the download.

```
- (void) downloadFileFrom:(NSString*) httpLocation respondAt:(SEL)selector on:(id)target withParam:(id)param
{
    self.finishSelector = selector;
    self.delegate = target;
    self.responseParams = param;
}
```

the Class is its own NSURLConnection delegate. Therefore the instance is separated from the others that I may instantiate, And it handles creating its own result for me to work with. I hold onto the param object. which could be anything.

At the end of the download it does a performSelector: on the delegate. passing itself to the delegate.

```
if ([self.target respondsToSelector:self.selector])
{
    [self.target performSelector:self.selector withObject:self.param];
}
```

then you can create an instance of the downloader and call your method... telling it where to reply to you.

```
MyDownloader downloader = [[MyDownloader alloc] init];
[downloader downloadFileFrom:@"http://www.mydomain.com/myimage" respondAt:@selector(myFileIsComplete:) on:self withParam: downloader];
[downloader autorelease];
```

another option is to create a @protocol for your class to respond at, and have you delegate conform to the responder.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but there is another option to consider. You could make a generic class that creates and calls the `NSURLConnection` provided they are common enough. Then keep an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` of the classes. One for each connection.

Example: I have an app that needs to download several photos simultaneously. Therefore, I have a `GetFlickrPhoto` class. It has a custom init method that receives the URL and any other necessary info. Each individual class creates the `NSURLConnection` and can safely set the delegate to `self`

This helps keep things contained and very manageable/reusable.

**To take it a step further:**

The app I mentioned before, also needed to download JSON feeds. So I made a `GenericDownload` class that took in URL and asynchronously downloaded the `NSData` and then returned the `NSData` to the calling delegate via defined success/failure protocols. It didn't care what the `NSData` contained.

I remodeled `GetFlickrPhoto` to call `GenericDownload` and use the returned `NSData` for a photo. I then made a `GetJSON` class that also called `GenericDownload` and parsed the returned `NSData` into a JSON feed.

Takes a bit more time but in the end you will be glad for maintenance and future projects.